# Generating DLL assembly dynamically at run time

Tags: c#, .net, dll, code-generation

Currently I have some code that is being generated dynamically.  In other words, a C# .cs file is created dynamically by the program, and the intention is to include this C# file in another project.

The challenge is that I would like to generate a .DLL file instead of generating a C# .cs file so that it could be referenced by any kind of .NET application (not only C#) and therefore be more useful.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.OutputAssembly = "AutoGen.dll";
CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, yourCodeAsString);
```

Adapted from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Comment: Note: older versions of this code have an extra line of code which create a compiler from the provider using CSharpCodeProvider.CreateCompiler(). This is deprecated, you should call compile on the provider directly.

Answer (score 36):

The non-deprecated way of doing it (using .NET 4.0 as previous posters mentioned):

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
public class J
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = "AutoGen.dll";

        CompilerResults r = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp").CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, "public class B {public static int k=7;}");

        //verify generation
        Console.WriteLine(Assembly.LoadFrom("AutoGen.dll").GetType("B").GetField("k").GetValue(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;` you can get the in-memory assembly with `r.CompiledAssembly`

Answer (score 5):

Right now, your best bet is [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx); the plans for 4.0 include "compiler as a service", which will make this fully managed.

Comment: title of topic is "generating-dll-assembly-dynamically-at-run-time" NOT "generating-EXE-assembly-dynamically-at-run-time" your link description abut create exe at runtime.

Comment: @AminGhaderi and who said anything about exe? If you mean "but the code sample on MSDN creates an exe" - it will happily create dlls too; ultimately, the file package is *not* the interesting part of an assembly

Answer (score 0):

An approach above doesn't seems work anymore (I've tried it from .Net core and .net framework 4.7.2 targeting project). I was getting "PlatformNotSupportedException" and to undestand, I've dived into source code and found this [piece](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3c33b4293107c607ae8669545114d6f9891432cb/src/libraries/System.CodeDom/src/Microsoft/CSharp/CSharpCodeGenerator.PlatformNotSupported.cs). And here is the explanation from them why it doesn't work and how to deal with this (link and documentation).

To be short (spoiler): I went to 1st link from there and it helped me. So, you can do it as described here: [how-to-compile-a-c-sharp-file-with-roslyn-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769630/how-to-compile-a-c-sharp-file-with-roslyn-programmatically). It may be treated as an possibe answer.