# create dll file in c#

Tags: c#, dll

How can I create a dll file in C#?

Comment: Please supply mind-numbingly vast amounts of additional detail.

Comment: create a Class Library project. Add code. Compile it. Voila!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I am not sure but maybe it is useful also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604501/generating-dll-assembly-dynamically-at-run-time

Answer (score 55, accepted):

File menu -> New Project -> choose your Programing language (Visual C#/VB etc.) -> Windows -> Class Library.

After the project has been created, make use of Build menu -> Build Solution (or Build [Project Name]) to compile the project.

You may find out the dll in the folder: project folder\bin\debug(or release)

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio as your IDE:

1. Create a new Class Library Project (File => New Project => Class Library)
2. Right click new project, select "Build"

DLL file will be found in a sub-folder of the new project (likely \bin\Debug)