# How to create dll that contain class in runTime ?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some class ( simple class ) and i want to compile in runtime this class and create ( in runtime ) some dll that will contain this class.

Is there some way to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `CSharpCodeProvider`, this could be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604501/generating-dll-assembly-dynamically-at-run-time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx).

You can read the [sample code](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) for "Snippy" that I used for C# in Depth - it does exactly this sort of thing.

You can ask `CSharpCodeProvider` to write to a file or build the assembly in memmory.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var options = new CompilerParameters {
            OutputAssembly = "Foo.dll"
        };
        string source = "public class Foo {}";

        provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { source });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CSharpCodeProvider` to complile code at run time. See [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dohollan/archive/2010/08/09/programmatically-invoke-the-c-compiler.aspx).

PS. Found by a quick google search ;)