# What version of C# does CSharpCodeProvider support?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compile a standalone C# file using the Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider in mscorlib version 4.

It's complaining about properties that are using expression bodies instead of statement bodies.

I.e., this it will compile:

```
protected Foo MyFoo
{
    get { return this.myFoo; }
}
```

But this it won't:

```
protected Foo MyFoo => this.myFoo;
```

Is there a more recent version of mscorlib I should be using?

Comment: Can you include the code used to compile the file?

Comment: Also, did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769630/how-to-compile-a-c-sharp-file-with-roslyn-programmatically

Comment: Pretty sure `CSharpCodeProvider` is severely deprecated.  You should probably look to a roslyn based solution.

Comment: System.CodeDom always uses the installed version of the framework and uses the C# compiler that is stored in the framework directory (normally c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319).  Just type "csc.exe" from the command line, it explicitly tells you which C# version it supports in its sign-on message.  That still doesn't say anything about the version on your user's machine.  But assuming you target at least 4.5 in your project, that will always be C# version 5.  Feature, not a bug, you don't have to worry about deploying Roslyn to the user's machine.   There is a Nuget package.