# Could not load file or assembly SharedLib.dll when DLL is compiled by Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to use Roslyn to compile DLL library. I tried various alternatives from [How to compile a C# file with Roslyn programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769630/how-to-compile-a-c-sharp-file-with-roslyn-programmatically) , let's say this one:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

namespace SharedLibCompile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string sourceCode = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Temp\SharedLib.cs");
            SyntaxTree syntaxTree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(SourceText.From(sourceCode));
            CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation
                .Create("SharedLib.dll")
                .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
                .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
                .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

            EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(@"c:\Temp\SharedLib.dll");
            if (!result.Success)
                Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Diagnostics.Select(diagnostic => diagnostic.ToString())));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is SharedLib.cs code:

```
using System;

namespace MyScript
{
    public class SharedLib
    {
        public static string GetGreeting()
        {
            return "Ahoy";
        }
    }
}
```

Dll compiles successfully, it could be also included into solution and compiled:

```
using System;
using MyScript;

namespace IncludeSharedLib
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(SharedLib.GetGreeting());
        }
    }
}
```

However if I try to use it in executable, I got error

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'SharedLib.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
> find the file specified.    at IncludeSharedLib.Program.Main(String[]
> args)

The error is there despite SharedLib.dll is in the same folder as IncludeSharedLib.exe. I tried to check the Dll with DotPeek and it looks good. What do I do wrong?

I use .Net Framework 4.8 in both solutions and the latest [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/) NuGet package.

Comment: You specify in `CSharpCompilation.Create(@"SharedLib.cs")` 'SharedLib.cs' as AssemblyName, but your output dll should be 'SharedLib.dll'. The two names do not match. Either specify 'SharedLib' as AssemblyName or 'SharedLib.cs.dll' as output dll.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Steeeve. I did a mistake when I prepared the question. This accumulated additional issue. I fixed the SharedLib.cs name issue. Now executable misses SharedLib.dll. That's more logical, but still I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The AssemblyName is still wrong. Note: AssemblyName is NOT the name of the output file! AssemblyName should not have any extension.

Comment: It works now with "SharedLib" assembly name. Thanks!