# How to compile C# code at runtime from another C# program

Tags: c#, compilation

I have a program that requires for it to read a file and compile the C# code inside of that file to an exe.

I tried using CSharpCodeProvider with CompileAssemblyFromFile because I used it in past programs but apparently it's outdated now and it gives out a 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'. So I'm looking for alternatives and examples. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't really understand roslyn so could you please provide an example?

Comment: Your original question "Why do I get a PlatformNotSupportedException exception when I use CSharpCodeProvider?" is answered by the link above. Before posting your next question, do some research into the solutions provided by that link, and be prepared to show your attempt.

Comment: @gunr2171 None of the references show how to use Roslyn to create an application, which apparently isn't straight forward, so not very helpful.

Comment: Try using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32770961/2557128) with the comment to leave off the extension so it may create an executable?

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid because of the mention of `PlatformNotSupportedException` and being that exception documented in the [remaks of that class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#remarks), looks like either .NET Core or .NET 5+