# Generating manifest when assembly (.dll) is generated at runtime using CodeDom.CompilerResults

Tags: c#, reflection, manifest, codedom

I'm generating an assembly (*.dll) at runtime. the compilation process is performed using CodeDom, as is recommended in following post:

[Generating DLL assembly dynamically at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604501/generating-dll-assembly-dynamically-at-run-time)

My code and assembly are generated successfully, not errors. The problem comes when I'm attempting load this generated assemblies at runtime via reflection using :

```
 // load for reflection only
 var _assemblyTempLoad = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly.FullName);
```

Following exception is thrown:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'nameforassembly.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest."

How to generate the manifest file or fix this issue?

I want clarify that assembly is generated at runtime, using following code:

```
CompilerResults compilerResult = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(compilerParameters, Path.Combine(path, sourceCodeFile));`
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it possible the file is either corrupt or compiled for the wrong framework or compiled for 64-bit and you are trying to load into a 32 bit process? You might get a more accurate error if you try to add the compiled dll into your project (just as a test).

Comment: Give the same you link to, you can specify the platform by adding a line like parameters.CompilerOptions = "/platform:anycpu" ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when an assembly is created at runtime (on the fly), the assembly info or metadata is not placed into assembly automatically. The use of the [Assembly] attribute was necessary too. On this way, the last step in the process was place the /platform argument to the compiler (thanks sgmoore). I can saw this using Redgate reflector. The assembly was shown without versioning and metadata attributes. Like this:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("[assembly: AssemblyTitle(\"{0}\")]", yourassembly.propertyfornamespace.Replace(" ", "")));
streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("[assembly: AssemblyDescription(\"{0}\")]", yourassembly.propertywithdescription));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following

```
compilerParameters.CompilerOptions = string.Format("/win32manifest: {0}", manifestFilename);
```

If you've already have the `CompilerOptions` set to some value, just concatenate the strings

```
compilerParameters.CompilerOptions += string.Format(" /win32manifest: {0}", manifestFilename);
```

[The win32manifest parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545961.aspx) tells the compiler to also generate a manifest file.