# Dynamically use runtime compiled assemlby

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, code-injection, dynamic-language-runtime

I compile code dynamically from code:

```
            string code = @"
                namespace CodeInjection
                {
                    public static class DynConcatenateString
                    {
                        public static string Concatenate(string s1, string s2){
                            return s1 + "" ! "" + s2;
                        }
                    }
                }";

            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604501/generating-dll-assembly-dynamically-at-run-time
            Console.WriteLine("Now doing some injection...");

            Console.WriteLine("Creating injected code in memory");


            CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            //parameters.OutputAssembly = "DynamicCode.dll"; // if specified creates the DLL
            CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
```

Then I can invoke the method with reflection:

```
                Console.WriteLine("Input two strings, and I will concate them with reflection:");
                var s1 = Console.ReadLine();
                var s2 = Console.ReadLine();
                var result = (string)results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString").GetMethod("Concatenate").Invoke(null, new object[] { s1, s2 });

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Result:");
                Console.WriteLine(result);
```

But I would like to invoke something like this:

```
                Console.WriteLine("Input two strings, and I will concate them with dynamic type:");
                var s1 = Console.ReadLine();
                var s2 = Console.ReadLine();

                dynamic type = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString");
                var resultA = (string)type.Concatenate(s1, s2); // runtime error
                // OR
                var resultB = (string)CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString.Concatenate(s1, s2); // compile error (cannot find assembly)


                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Result:");
                Console.WriteLine(resultA);
                Console.WriteLine(resultB);
```

The resultB would be better. Any ideas how to do it? I need strictly .NET 4.0, we have not updated to 4.5 yet (because the half of the team uses VS 2010). (I can invoke with reflection, I know, I am just looking for another way, because we need to test dyn. code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `dynamic` directly in this scenario. `dynamic` always requires a class instance, but you are trying to call a method in a static class, hence you don't have a class instance.

However, you can create a helper class and use that in combination with `dynamic`:

```
public class StaticMethodInvoker : DynamicObject
{
    Type _containingType;

    public StaticMethodInvoker(Type containingType)
    {
        _containingType = containingType;
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(
        InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, out Object result)
    {
        result = _containingType.InvokeMember
            binder.Name,
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public,
            null, null, args);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var type = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString");
dynamic DynConcatenateString = new StaticMethodInvoker(type);
string result = DynConcatenateString.Concatenate(s1, s2);
```

Comment: thank you, now I can simplify it with one static method for testing (like dynamic d = MyStaticInvoker.Create(results, "MyClassName"); d.UseMyFunc(with, parameters))

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a `static` method. With `dynamic` you bypass the check but actually you're trying to call `Concatenate()` on the `System.Type` for `CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString`.

First of all make it an instance method:

```
public class DynConcatenateString
{
    public string Concatenate(string s1, string s2){
        return s1 + "" ! "" + s2;
    }
}
```

Now let's see your code:

```
dynamic type = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString");
```

This is a `System.Type`, not an object of type `CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString`. If you change `dynamic` to `var` you'll see the right type at compile time. You have then to create an instance of that type, like this:

```
var type = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString");
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

For the syntax B there is no hope in C# because `CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString` doesn't exist at compile time then that line will fail.

If you **must** keep it static then all you can do is to use reflection to invoke that method (`dynamic` is then useless). Don't worry about performance hit...DLR isn't much faster than plain Reflection (as AFAIK it's how it's implemented with a touch of caching).

Comment: I was looking for static solution but I will also need for instances later. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use generic types?
Define your class interface:

```
    public interface IDynConcatenateString 
    {
        string Concatenate(string s1, string s2);
    }
```

And then generate dinamic code

```
    public T GetInstanceOf<T>(string code, string typename)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Now doing some injection...");

        Console.WriteLine("Creating injected code in memory");


        CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        //parameters.OutputAssembly = "DynamicCode.dll"; // if specified creates the DLL
        CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);

        //type name = "CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString"

        T codeclass = (T)results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(typename);

        return codeclass;

    }
```

Try to execute like this...

```
public void Exec() 
    {
        string code = @"
            namespace CodeInjection
            {
                public class MyDynConcatenateString : IDynConcatenateString 
                {
                    public string Concatenate(string s1, string s2){
                        return s1 + "" ! "" + s2;
                    }
                }
            }";
        IDynConcatenateString writer = GetInstanceOf<IDynConcatenateString>(
            code, "CodeInjection.MyDynConcatenateString");

        var s1 = Console.ReadLine();
        var s2 = Console.ReadLine();
        var result = writer.Concatenate(s1, s2);

        Console.WriteLine(result);

    }
```

The IDynConcatenateString implementation is dynamic, defined in the "code" variable, as a parameter of Exec method.
You only need to define the interface, and no need to hardcode method names or class names.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this? The problem remains: `MyDynConcatenateString` is a static class. As such it can't implement an interface and it can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was an interesting usage, so I made a convenience version of my [LateType](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/LateType)'s constructor `LateType(Assembly assembly, String typename)`in my open source portable library [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey)

```
dynamic DynConcatenateString = new DynamicObjects.LateType(cr.CompiledAssembly, "CodeInjection.DynConcatenateString");

Assert.That("1 ! 2", Is.EqualTo(DynConcatenateString.Concatenate("1","2")));
```