# Store .Net classes in Oracle database?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

Does anyone know how to store .Net classes or assemblies in Oracle database in order to load them later dynamically ?

I'm creating assemblies at run time using the code in [Generating DLL assembly dynamically at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604501/generating-dll-assembly-dynamically-at-run-time)

Thanks.

Comment: This question shows how to store blobs in the DB. https://community.oracle.com/thread/340580. You can then retrieve them, save them to disk and load them using Assembly.LoadFrom see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658498/how-to-load-assembly-to-appdomain-with-all-references-recursively

Comment: Google ORM databases and checkout technologies such as Hibernate.

Comment: @ojbkass : That's not what I really need. I'm trying to map business objects with relational databases. All what I need is to store assembly and load it at run time

Comment: ORMs are built specifically to map business objects to relational databases. You are going the long way around if you are compiling dynamic objects to do the same thing. While you can copy the BLOB from Oracle (or any other database that supports binary large objects), you will still have to write that to a file, load the dll, and execute whatever code you need to run. You may have to deal with UAE issues too.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman thanks. Do you have any example or link on how to do that please ?

Comment: [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef), [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), [Dapper.NET](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/). Look at their documentation. Most have a Getting Started page.