# C# dynamic creation of Assembly out of classes

Tags: c#, class, dll, .net-assembly

How can one create a .dll dynamically from code out of several classes?

Creation-example:

```
 var test = CodeDomProvider
   .CreateProvider("CSharp")
   .CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, "public class MyClass { ... }");
```

CompileAssemblyFromSource expects a string (representation of a class).

I do not want to provide every class which shall be in the generated assembly as a string, so I want to pass them on creation.

Example:

```
  public class MyClass
  {
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public bool Valid{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string SomeText{ get; set; }
  }
```

Is there something like

```
var test = CodeDomProvider
  .CreateProvider("CSharp")
  .CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, MyClass);
```

Comment: This link should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604501/generating-dll-assembly-dynamically-at-run-time

Comment: This is exactly the approach I am using. The guy in the answer uses "yourCodeAsString", but this is the culprit.

Comment: use `File.ReadAllText` on the .cs file that contains the class definition?

Comment: Does not work for some reason, I tried it and the assembly will not be created this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

add "ReferencedAssemblies" to the parameters passed as first argument to CompileAssemblyFromSource.

```
var parameters = new CompilerParameters
      {
        GenerateExecutable = false,
        OutputAssembly = MY_ASSEMBLY,
        ReferencedAssemblies = {"System.Core.dll", "System.ServiceModel.dll"}
      };
```